# Ant Design- Form validation only when click outside a field

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, antd

I have an email field in a form and it validates whether it's a valid email after each value change (e.g. it shows an error "email is not a valid email" as you keep typing).

How can we change it to just validate when you click out of that field or when you submit the form?

Here is the form from their examples:

```
return (
    <Form {...layout} name="nest-messages" onFinish={onFinish} validateMessages={validateMessages} component={false}>
        <Form.Item name={['user', 'name']} label="Name" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
            <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item name={['user', 'email']} label="Email" rules={[{ type: 'email' }]}>
            <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item name={['user', 'age']} label="Age" rules={[{ type: 'number', min: 0, max: 99 }]}>
            <InputNumber />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item name={['user', 'website']} label="Website">
            <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item name={['user', 'introduction']} label="Introduction">
            <Input.TextArea />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ ...layout.wrapperCol, offset: 8 }}>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                Submit
            </Button>
        </Form.Item>
    </Form>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the issue:[link](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/15818#issuecomment-524202029) you need to pass the `validationTrigger` prop.